# Overwrite file contents. Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I have a batch file, and i need to move a folder from one directory to another. 
I can do that no problem. But, im hitting a problem after that.

The folder i just moved is created at run time, then moved to the final destination folder where it needs to remain, unless the user decides to delete it.

So, if the user runs the batch file a second time, when it tries to move the run time folder, there is already the old version of the folder at the destination and it gives a "permission denied" error.

So my question is, what is the best way to overwrite the contents of a folder from a batch file?

Right now i am just using the move command. Which works fine for overwriting regular files, but it cannot overwrite folders apparently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Would suggest to use either xcopy or robocopy for Overwriting folders
```

`Xcopy /E /Y` would Overwrite folder ,

please find More options `Xcopy /?`

Please note that i have mentioned this options only to overwrite and not to move folder.

Comment: That looks like it did the trick. I was in the middle of looking into xcopy, but i was missing the /y command.

Is there a way to do a silent copy so it doesnt show all the files being moved?

Comment: yes try xcopy /E /Y /Q , for silent copy of files , please accept my answer if you found that helpful so that other can use it. :)